# Refresh standard page in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, formula-field, roll-up-summary, refresh

I have a formula data field on an object which is not reflecting updated values when viewing it in Lightning. This is directly related to the known issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU.

The workaround given there is to use force:refreshView. Problem is we don't have any Lightning components and all examples I've looked at seem to use only that.

The formula field is a calculation: fieldA - fieldB - fieldC where all 3 fields are roll-up summary fields of 2 different child records.  When the child records are updated, the parent formula field should update with the new value. It does in Classic, but not in Lightning - only after refreshing (sometimes 3 times) does it show the new calculation.

How can I force the parent object page to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to disable secure and persistent Browser Caching in Setup under Session Settings / Caching. But it comes at a price.

Without a custom lightning component, I wouldn't know of any other way to force the refresh.